# Easier to save static HTML to a database field, or read static HTML from a file?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Our Java/JSP application has a "Here are the terms and conditions you're agreeing to" page.   I've just been handed the requirement to save this agreement text - essentially the entire JSP page - with the user's record.  Currently it's embedded in the JSP page as static text, like so:

```
        <div>
        <h2>General Terms & Conditions</h2>
        <div >
            <p>You agree to sell your soul and work for free.  Also, you agree to wash all our cars by hand twice a week.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

At first I thought it might be better to pull this text into a property file so I can access it from multiple places in the app:

```
    <div>
        <h2>General Terms & Conditions</h2>
        <div >
            <p><fmt:message key='termsAndConditions.youAreDoomed'/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But even that won't give me what I need, which is basically the entire text as a string.

The other alternative I thought of would be to read the entire HTML or text agreement into the JSP page from an outside file - that would also give me access to the pre-formatted text in my Java code.   But it seems like it would be a pain.

Is there a better way to do this?  Is there some way to grab the HTML or text of the entire rendered page into a String, so I can save it in the record?  I'm trying to do as little refactoring as possible because this app needs to go live "ASAP."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the entire HTML or text agreement into the JSP page and store it in an variable:

```
<c:import url="/termsAndConditions.html" var="agreement" />
```

To output it:

```
<c:out value="${agreement}" />
```

To output it directly without storing:

```
<c:import url="/termsAndConditions.html" />
```

To access the variable from scriptlets:

```
<c:import url="/termsAndConditions.html" var="agreement" />
<%
    String termsAndConditions = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("agreement");
%>
```

To declare scope of the variable (default is `page` scope):

```
<c:import url="/termsAndConditions.html" var="agreement" scope="application" />
```

To use core JSTL library add at the beginning of the JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: Is there any way to process the JSP file inside a Java routine?  I apologize if I'm having "brain fade" here, but I can't think of any way to do this.   I was hoping for something like  `String myText=magicFunction("/termsAndConditions.html")`  but that may be impossible.

Comment: A related application I'm aware of handles this through doing an internal HTTP request using HTTPClient:   http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

Comment: This is actually what I asked for, so I'm marking it "correct", and I'll ask another question if I get stuck again.  Thanks!